# How to perform dynamic Change detection for a object

Tags: angular

I have 2 components

1. Customer Component
2. Preview Component

**Customer class**

```
export class Customer {
  public firstname:string;
  public lastname:string;
  public designation:string;
  public company:string;
}
```

**customer.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='customer.firstname' placeholder="First Name">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='customer.lastname' placeholder="Last Name">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='customer.designation' placeholder="Designation">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='customer.company' placeholder="Company">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <iGlobal-preview [customer]='customer'></iGlobal-preview>
  </div>
</div>
```

**customer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'app/models/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'iGlobal-customer',
  templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer.component.scss']
})
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

customer:Customer;

  constructor() {
    this.customer = new  Customer();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
click(){
  console.log("customer",this.customer)
}
}
```

**preview.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <textarea name="preview" [(ngModel)]='previewtext' rows="10" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

**preview.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'app/models/customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'iGlobal-preview',
  templateUrl: './preview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./preview.component.scss']
})
export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input("customer")
  customer:Customer

  previewtext:string="";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.previewtext = "Customer Name : "+this.customer.firstname+" "+this.customer.lastname
  }

}
```

My requirement is to show the preview of whatever is entered in customer component, pass the object to preview component and perform some action later on on preview component.

How to do this change detection correctly so that i can get any changes made on parent component on to child component?

Comment: u need to implement ngOnChanges like this --> ```ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) { if (changes.customer.currentvalue) { this.customer = changes.customer.currentValue; }``` this lifecyclehook ngOnChanges updates the input any time it changes from the outside. If it helped I will provide an answer

Comment: @sagat No, not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of being dependent on the ngOnInit method I would bind the textarea like this:

```
<textarea name="preview" value="{{'Customer Name : ' + customer.firstname + ' ' + customer.lastname}}" rows="10" style="width: 100%"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnPush Change Detection Strategy like shown below in customer preview component

```
  import { OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'app/models/customer';
    @Component({
      selector: 'iGlobal-preview',
      templateUrl: './preview.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./preview.component.scss'],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    })

    Implement OnChnage Life cycle hook
    export class PreviewComponent implements OnInit, OnChange {
    customer: Customer ;
    ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
        if (changes.customer && changes.customer.currentValue) {
          this.customer = changes.customer.currentValue; // You will get always latest customer object whenever there is a change in customer object in the parent
          console.log(changes.customer.currentValue);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: No this is not working for me, am I missing anything?

Comment: Change detection will work only for mutable objects. I mean if you just update a property of a object then it won't trigger change detection. Create a function and pass key and value on each textbox blur or text change event. And in component controller create new object with new values. Then change detection will work. Remember always we need to have Mutable objects to improve the performance